Why this snippet returns 0 gradients? Pytorch RNN understanding
I'm trying to understand how slicing the output affects the gradients in a RNN. I built this simple script.
# Test the gradient of a RNN 

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable

rnn = nn.RNN(10, 20, 1)
input = Variable(torch.randn(5, 3, 10), requires_grad=True)
h0 = Variable(torch.randn(1, 3, 20), requires_grad=True)
output, hn = rnn(input, h0)

output = output[:, 1:, :]

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

target = Variable(torch.empty((5,2), dtype=torch.long).random_(20), requires_grad=False)

loss = loss_fn(output.reshape(-1, output.shape[2]), target.view(-1))
loss.backward()

print(input.grad[:,0,:])


I would assume that the gradients are different from zero because, even if I have calculated the loss on a sliced input, the hidden states at subsequent time steps are still affected by the input at the first step. So why the gradients are zero?

The gradient is zero because you are slicing along the batch axis, not the time step/sequence axis.
By default, nn.RNN assumes the input will be of shape (sequence_length, batch_size, input_size).
When you slice your output as output = output[:, 1:, :], you are slicing the batch dimension. This means the first item in your batch is entirely excluded from the gradient computation - you are cutting out all time steps for the first batch item.
If you slice along the sequence_length axis, you can see that the first timestep has a gradient even when excluded from the loss calculation:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

rnn = nn.RNN(10, 20, 1)

x = torch.randn(5, 3, 10, requires_grad=True)
h0 = torch.randn(1, 3, 20, requires_grad=True)

output, hn = rnn(x, h0)

output = output[1:, :, :] # slice sequence_length axis

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# change (5,2) to (4,3) due to different slicing
target = torch.empty((4,3), dtype=torch.long).random_(20)

loss = loss_fn(output.reshape(-1, output.shape[2]), target.view(-1))

loss.backward()

# grad of first timestep 
print(x.grad[0,:,:])

Note that you can pass batch_first=True to nn.RNN if you want to structure your inputs as (batch_size, sequence_length, input_size)
